# How to initialize const array in variadic class template?

Tags: c++, templates, initialization, variadic-templates

I need to initialize a const array filled with smallest multiples of parameter A larger than numbers given as parameter B.

for now, I have something like this

```
template<std::size_t A, std::size_t... B>
class class_name
{
        const int arr[sizeof...(B)] = {B...};
}
```

but instead of filling `arr` with values given in B, I want to fill it with smallest multiples of A that are larger than values given in B. Is it even possible?

Comment: Oh, I think it's possible, but it's a lot of work. 1) One helper meta-template that produces `(std::max<B...>+(A-1))/A*A`, in so many words, 2) A second helper meta-template that specializes `std::index_sequence`, to produce `(i*A)...`, and 3) The grand finale adds 1 and 2 together.

Comment: let's say B-element is some element of B, then i could do smth like
 `(B-element/A + 1) * A` for each element, but i have no idea if I can use it somehow/how could I use it.

Comment: `const int arr[sizeof...(B)] = {( (B + (A-1))/A*A )...};` Is this what you are looking for? [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b51jPaGEd)

Comment: `const int arr[sizeof...(B)] = {( ((B/A) + 1)*A )...};` if you need strictly greater. The previous attempt made it greater-or-equal.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik wait, you can just do something like `(B+1)...` and it will give you initializer list with elements of B with this math applied on them?

Comment: I interpret "larger than numbers given as parameter B" to mean "more than max(B...)". Come to think of it, there are several different ways to interpret it, this should be clarified. But, yes, if this means "next multiple of A after each value of B", then this is trivial to the point of being un-interesting.

Comment: @Crimsoon Yes, has always been possible.

Comment: Behold the magic of [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It is not a fold expression in this case though.

Comment: damn ,that explains a lot, thanks. I think it's an answer

Comment: @user17732522 Right. I'll come in again. Behold the magic of [pack expansion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Pack_expansion)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Don't know whether it has a specific name other than pack expansion in an initializer-list. Fold expressions are single expressions, not initializer lists. The difference here is important because fold expressions have only been added with C++17.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik will you post an answer, or is it ok for me to post it?

Comment: @Crimsoon Sidenote, depends on your take, it might be slightly clearer to wrap it in a function like `make_number`, [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4GrYoM1o7)